# How set major dimension in google spreadsheets api?

Tags: spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I need to set the majorDimension value using the google spreadsheet API. I already read the documentation and it just says that I can set the value to ROW or COLUMN, but it doesn't talk about how I can do it in the URL.

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#dimension

> URL: https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/!A1:C1 (where here I set the value of majorDimension?)

Comment: What method do you want to use in Sheets API?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was solved by adding majorDimension value to the requesting url.

Here is the example for **COLUMN Dimension**

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{SpreadSheetID}/values/{Range}?majorDimension=COLUMNS&key={APIKey}
```

For **ROW Dimension**

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{SpreadSheetID}/values/{Range}?key={APIKey}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a change to a Sheet, you need to use the `update` method. Follow [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update), it will explain to you how to craft the request,and for the request's body you'd only need:

```
{
  "majorDimension": "ROWS"
}
```

The request looks like this:

`https://content-sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/SHEET_ID/values/A1%3AC2?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&alt=json&key=KEY`

I suggest you use the **try this API** option in the `update` method page (linked above).